# Detecting and Writing if ALL_BUILD was run from CMake

Tags: c++, xcode, visual-studio, cmake

I am creating a project that is built using CMake requires some special packaging afterwards. I would like to ensure that the build is release and that every part has been built in release. I wrote the build type using the following code:

```
FUNCTION ( GetCMakeBuildType ret)
    # Returns the generator string to get the current build type:
    SET(${ret} "$<$<CONFIG:MinSizeRel>:MinSizeRel>$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:Debug>$<$<CONFIG:Release>:Release>$<$<CONFIG:RelWithDebInfo>:RelWithDebInfo>" PARENT_SCOPE)
ENDFUNCTION()

FUNCTION ( WriteBuildType )   
    GetCMakeBuildType(buildTypeString)
    ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(RecordBuildType ALL COMMAND echo ${buildTypeString} > ./target/build_type.txt)
ENDFUNCTION()
```

But I would also like to detect if ALL the libraries were built by determining if ALL_BUILD was the target or if they only built a single library while the rest is in debug. Can I detect if the user ran ALL_BUILD and write a flag to file to note that packaging is okay?

Comment: read about [`cpack`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CPack.html).

Comment: @MarekR In this case, cpack won't work well for supporting the combination of new and legacy code. My understanding for both cpack and install targets is that I may be able to tag certain configurations (debug, RelWithDebug), but at this time I need to understand if I can identify when `ALL_BUILD`  was used versus not.